# Reference marker by ID

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a set of markers on my map and am trying to update their position form an ajax call...
The ajax call works fine and I can loop through the new values; however I cannot find a way to reference the markers (say by ID) so I can update their latLng.

Basically in the end I will need to..
1.) Obtain a reference to a marker by a unique id
2.) Possibly loop through all markers

Thanks in advance - I am new and need a little help getting going - hopefully I can pass along the good will when I can :)

Code for ajax below - I the part about modifying the location of the marker is the part I don't know how to do - so in the code below I just add a new marker where I would really need to just update the position

```
var json = $.getJSON("json/tracking.php",function(data){

        console.log("updated");

        $.each(data,function(key,value){
        //console.log(value.unit + " " + value.lat + " " + value.lng);

        new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat,value.lng),
        });


        });
    })
    .success(function(){
        //console.log("success");
        })
    .error(function(){
        //console.log("error");
        })
    .complete(function(){
        //console.log("complete");
    });
},2000);
```

Comment: Show your code, will be less work for me to try to help :)

Comment: Edited my post - maybe that will explain it :) Thanks in adavance -

Comment: How are these markers created? Are they created in the `getJSON` you posted? Does the JSON contain an ID for each marker? Yes, you need individual references to each marker then call something like `markerRef.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat,value.lng));`. If this is not helpful enough, do show me more code and a portion of your JSON.

Comment: I was thinking that I would loop through - check if the marker existed - if so then update position - if not then create it. The next would be get rid of any marker that is not in the json. I just am unsure of how to get a reference to the marker (markerRef) in your example. I was thinking that maybe there was something like GetMarkerbyID(id) or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inclined to store these in an array of objects as I create them, with any other information (e.g. id) stored as a property of the object. So create a markers array in the appropriate scope (probably outside of the scope of the json callback):

```
var markers = [];

var json = ...

  markers.push({
    id: //.. your unique id, or index
    obj: new google.maps.Marker(...
  });
```

Comment: I will try that... that looks like the way I would have to go if there is no way to just get maps to 'findmarkerbyid' (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach: I'm assuming your JSON is consistent in ordering the markers. `newData` is pretending to be the new JSON data, when the map is clicked (outside a marker), the "new data" is fetched.

Here's the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/167/)

```
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


  var data = [{unit:1, lat:0, lng:0},
              {unit:2, lat:10, lng:0},
              {unit:3, lat:20, lng:0}
             ];

  var newData = [{unit:1, lat:0, lng:10},
                 {unit:2, lat:10, lng:20},
                 {unit:3, lat:20, lng:30}
                ];


  var markers = {};

  $.each(data,function(key,value){
    //console.log(value.unit + " " + value.lat + " " + value.lng);

    markers[key] = markers[key] || new google.maps.Marker({ map: map });
    markers[key].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat,value.lng));
    markers[key].setTitle(value.unit.toString());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    $.each(newData,function(key,value){
      //console.log(value.unit + " " + value.lat + " " + value.lng);

      markers[key] = markers[key] || new google.maps.Marker({ map: map });
      markers[key].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat,value.lng));
      markers[key].setTitle(value.unit.toString());
    });

  });
}
```